# Get direct link to file from Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, curl, wget

If I paste in

```
https://exchange.nagios.org/components/com_mtree/attachment.php?link_id=3355&cf_id=24
```

in my browser, then it downloads a file called `check_cups_printer.tar.gz`.

If I

```
wget 'https://exchange.nagios.org/components/com_mtree/attachment.php?link_id=3355&cf_id=24'
```

then I get a file called `attachment.php?link_id=3355&cf_id=24`.

**Question**

Is there a way from command line to get the direct link to the file?

Comment: Cross-site duplicate https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74334/how-to-download-files-with-wget-where-the-page-makes-you-wait-for-download `curl -O -J -L https://...` works for me

Comment: Another possible (cross-site) duplicate - https://superuser.com/questions/301044/how-to-wget-a-file-with-correct-name-when-redirected

Comment: @TomFenech I am looking for the direct link, where these are about downloading the file with correct file name.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your `wget` version, you might be able to use the `--content-disposition` flag.

On my system I have the following version installed `GNU Wget 1.19.1` and using this
`--content-disposition` flag, the file is downloaded with the original name intact.

```
wget --content-disposition 'https://exchange.nagios.org...'
```

In my man pages they warn that this is an experimental feature -

> If this is set to on, experimental (not fully-functional) support for "Content-Disposition" headers is enabled...

Answer (score -2):

You can use the `-O` option for `wget`. It is the shorthand option of `--output-document=file`.

This option tells `wget` to output the contents it is downloading into a file.

For your example, what you would need to do is -

```
wget -O name_of_output_file 'https://exchange.nagios.org...'
```

Comment: I think the issue is that wget doesn't follow the redirection.

Comment: @TomFenech - For me it does actually download the desired file - only the name gets messed up. Changing the file extension to `.tar.gz` allows me to access the contents.